# Will NpgsqlPoint be Updated to use Double Precision

Tags: c#-4.0, postgresql-9.3, npgsql

I noticed in Npgsql version 2.1.3 that the type NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlPoint is using single-precision values.  However, the documentation for all types that use points (point, path, polygon, etc.) in Postgres v9.3+ indicates it is using 16 bytes to store the values, which implies double precision storage.  Is there any plan to update NpgsqlPoint to use double-precision, or am I misreading the Postgres documentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are absolutely correct. We are now working on a major overhaul for Npgsql v3.0, where this has already been fixed and NpgsqlPoint has doubles (unfortunately this version is still in alpha).

Comment: The status of Npgsql v3.0 can be found [here](https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/milestones/3.0).  The bug fix for this particular issue can be found [here](https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/issues/437).

Comment: The NuGet package for Npgsql v3.0 rc2 was released on July 17, 2015.